# Force type argument inference not to use any[] for an array (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing a Typescript library that handle type-validation.

I have this working code:

```js
type MyTypePredicate<T> = (value: any) => value is T

function createTypePredicateForArrayT<T>(item: T): MyTypePredicate<T[]> {
    return ((value: any) => /* Real code here */ true) as MyTypePredicate<T[]>
}

// This can be use with or without providing the generic T.
const t1 = createTypePredicateForArrayT<number>(42)
const t2 = createTypePredicateForArrayT(42)
// Both t1 and t2 will have the type MyTypePredicate<number[]>
```

However, purely for consistency with a set of other function in the library, I would prefer to let the provided generic to be same as type as the generic in the returned `MyTypePredicate<T>`

This can be done with

```js
function createTypePredicateForArrayA<A extends any[]>(item: A[number]): MyTypePredicate<A> {
    return ((value: any) => /* Real code here */ true) as MyTypePredicate<A>
}

// which make this working:
const a1 = createTypePredicateForArrayA<number[]>(42)

// ...but the argument inference stops working,
const a2 = createTypePredicateForArrayA(42)
// it gives a2 the type MyTypePredicate<any[]> and not MyTypePredicate<number[]>
```

Is there a way to rewrite the second, and still make both a1 and a2 to work?

Comment: In any event, messing around with inference is more of an art than a science; perhaps [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mM86kN) meets your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That is a good approach, and it works! Thankyou! Would be even better without a second argument, but guess it is not possible.
I have updated the question, and removed `X | any`, since I understand it can distract this problem.

Comment: Okay, I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward approach is to write it your first way, and just let the compiler infer the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument.  The additional constraint that the type argument must represent a particular function of the types you care about necessarily complicates things; it's difficult/impossible to have a single type argument work one way with explicit specification and another way with type inference.

---

One way to get things to work as you request is to add a second type parameter so that you use the first one only for explicit specification and the second one for type inference:

```
function createTypePredicateForArrayA<
    A extends any[],
    T = A[number]
>(item: T): MyTypePredicate<T[]> {
    return ((value: any) => /* Real code here */ true) as MyTypePredicate<T[]>
}
```

Let's test it:

```
const a1 = createTypePredicateForArrayA<number[]>(42)
// const a1: MyTypePredicate<number[]>

const a2 = createTypePredicateForArrayA(42)
// const a2: MyTypePredicate<number[]>
```

In the `a1` case you are explicitly specifying `A` as `number[]`.  Since TypeScript does not currently support *partial type argument inference* (as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)), then the `T` type argument is also specified and not inferred.  As such, it ends up falling back to its [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `A[number]`, which means that `T` is `number` and you are forced to pass in a `number` argument for `item` and you get `number[]` out.

In the `a2` case you are letting the compiler infer `A` and `T`.  There is no inference site for `A`, so that just defaults to `any[]`. But `item` is an inference site for `T`, so that defaults to `number`, and thus the return type is `number[]`.

---

Another way to do it is to give your function two call signatures; one for type argument inference, and one for manual specification.  That is, make it an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
function createTypePredicateForArrayA<A extends any[] = never>(
    item: A[number]): MyTypePredicate<A>; // manual
function createTypePredicateForArrayA<T>(item: T): MyTypePredicate<T[]>; // infer
```

Let's test it:

```
const a1 = createTypePredicateForArrayA<number[]>(42)
// const a1: MyTypePredicate<number[]>

const a2 = createTypePredicateForArrayA(42)
// const a2: MyTypePredicate<number[]>
```

In the `a1` case you manually specify `A` as `number[]`, which makes the compiler select the first overload, which behaves as you expect.  In the `a2` case you do not specify the type argument; the first overload fails because there is no inference site for `A`, and thus it falls back to the `never` default, and `42` does not match... so it tries the second overload, and now you get the straightforward inference behavior for `T` as you expect.

---

So there you go; two relatively complicated approaches to the relatively complicated problem of struggling against the intended behavior of TypeScript's inference with generic functions.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAVA7gexQTxhAggE4DmArpMAC5RIDeAsAFACQluyAstjngAqEQAJgEt4IShAA8KAHxIAvEgAUANxAAbUhABcSEMGwBKBXLWbkwmiiZNmAM1LB4lYRmBJ4A8RB4R+Q0W8AMQxCIkIQbHxJW2Z8JAgADwlgQRp9bABtAF0AGliUBSR8TOByACMIQmzbGSVhCTBdFENdLl9-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)

Comment: Wow! The secod approch with overloading is solving it all the way! I doubted it was possible. Amazing! Thankyou!